# Generate JS array that determines sorted rank

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a complex array (for the use case of tabular data displayed in columns and rows) lets say I have some values:

```
var values = [
    [234, 386, 21, 38],
    [-23, 58, 106, 0],
    [45, -48, 506, 23],
    [109, 168, 42, 111]
];
```

What would be the best way to return a matching array that would rank the values against their **column** in the correct (maintained) order? The ranked order would be highest to lowest in this case.

For example, an end result array of:

```
[
    [1, 1, 4, 2],
    [4, 3, 2, 4],
    [3, 4, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 3, 1]
];
```

Note how the result is sorted vertically by column.

I would want to use this with a large data set, so any guidance/tips for quickest performance is my aim here.

--

For context: My first attempt was to map the original array with the index values, but I was unsure where to go from there:

```
var singleColumn = [234, -23, 45, 109];
for (var i = 0; i < singleColumn.length; i++) {
    singleColumn[i] = [singleColumn[i], i];
}
```

Comment: Define "best way". And what have you tried?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your 'end result array' does not seem to be sorted at all?

Comment: please add some mor explanation how the start values became the end result.

Comment: The sorting is up and down. Look at the first column (234, -23, 45, 109) so that rank order is (1, 4, 3, 2) which is what we see in the first column of the result array,

Comment: What is current algorithm to arrive at _"end result array"_ ?

Comment: @JohnHascall ahh i see, thanks...

Comment: I would construct an array of each column value and position, for example, from the first column: `[ {234, 0}, {-23,1}, {45, 2}, {109, 3} ],` then sort that (on the 1st values), giving `[ {234, 0},  {109, 3} ], {45, 2}, {-23,1} ]`.  Now we have the info to construct the first column of the result array by adding 1 to each of those 2nd values `[ 0+1, 3+1, 2+1, 1+1 ]`.  repeat for each column

Comment: "Best way" was merely saying the simplest/performance friendly way, as I wasn't sure really where to start. I was trying to generate an array of indexes and use them to sort, but I wasn't able to wrap my head around what to do with them. The "algorithm" as stated above is just sorting them largest to smallest (ascending). And as stated by @JohnHascall above, the values are by column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the trick will be retaining original indices after the sort. I've iterated them into a data structure first, sorted it, and then rebuilt the 2-dimensional array structure from the result.

I haven't done any checking to ensure that the input is all well-formed, the assumption is all rows are the same width as the first row.

An optimization that could probably be done would be transforming the raw values into the data-structure during the sort, which would eliminate a pass of the array. I don't see an easy way to do that without losing some of the conciseness and readability, and it would be a pretty small gain.

```js
var values = [
    [234, 386, 21, 38],
    [-23, 58, 106, 0],
    [45, -48, 506, 23],
    [109, 168, 42, 111]
];

function buildRanking(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
    //everything inside this for loop is per column

    //first use map function to turn the column into an array of objects
    //each holding the value and the current index. [{value: 234, index: 1}, etc..]
    var sortableStructure = values.map(function(val, i) {
      return { value : val[col], index : i };
    });

    //Sort function to sort my sortableStructure in place on the values
    sortableStructure.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });

    //now iterate over the sortable strucutre
    for(var i = 0; i < sortableStructure.length; i++) {
      //this ugly bit just makes sure arrays are initialized for each row as needed
      if(typeof result[sortableStructure[i].index] === 'undefined')
          result[sortableStructure[i].index] = [];

     //for the current item in the sortableStructure, get the index
     //access the result element corresponding to that index 
     //(the original position of this sorted value) and push in 
     //the current index (sort order) + 1 (to switch from zero-based to one-based)
      result[sortableStructure[i].index].push(i + 1);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//To provide visible output.
document.write(JSON.stringify(buildRanking(values)).split('],[').join('],<br/>['));
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass at this and highly unoptimized but here's a loose implementation where I do it step by step.

```
function sort(rows) {

  var columns = [];

   /* Invert rows and columns */

  for (var i = 0, row; i < rows.length; i++) {
    row = rows[i];
    for (var j = 0, col; j < row.length; j++) {
      col = rows[i][j];
      columns[j] = columns[j] || [];
      columns[j][i] = col;
    }
  }

  /* Sort by descending order, returning index */

  var sortedColumns = columns.slice(0).map(function(column, i) {
    return column.slice(0).sort(function(a, b) {
      return b - a;
    }).map(function(value, j, sortedColumn) {
      return sortedColumn.indexOf(column[j]) + 1;
    });
  });


  /* Invert rows and columns back again */

  var sortedRows = [];

    for (var i = 0, row; i < sortedColumns.length; i++) {
    row = sortedColumns[i];
    for (var j = 0, col; j < row.length; j++) {
      col = sortedColumns[i][j];
      sortedRows[j] = sortedRows[j] || [];
      sortedRows[j][i] = col;
    }
  }

  return sortedRows;
}

var values = [
  [234, 386, 21, 38],
  [-23, 58, 106, 0],
  [45, -48, 506, 23],
  [109, 168, 42, 111]
];

var expected = [
  [1, 1, 4, 2],
  [4, 3, 2, 4],
  [3, 4, 1, 3],
  [2, 2, 3, 1]
];

var sorted = sort(values);

console.log(sorted.toString() === expected.toString()); // true
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7ek6pz63/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns habe to be sorted descending and the result is based on one, then this should work.

```js
var values = [
        [234, 386, 21, 38],
        [-23, 58, 106, 0],
        [45, -48, 506, 23],
        [109, 168, 42, 111]
    ];

function getX(array) {
    var length = array[0].length,
        result = Array.apply(null, { length: array.length }).map(function () { return []; }),
        temp, i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp = [];
        array.forEach(function (a, j) {
            temp.push({ v: a[i], i: j });
        });
        temp.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.v - a.v;
        }).forEach(function (a, j) {
            result[a.i][i] = j + 1;
        });
    }
    return result;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getX(values), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```